# Requesting User Roles With Auth0 And Next Auth

Tags: next.js, middleware, auth0, next-auth

I'm just wondering, what do I need to add to my Auth0 setup so I can use restricted routes as outlined in the [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware):

```js
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware"

export default withAuth(
  // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
  function middleware(req) {
    console.log(req.nextauth.token)
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token }) => token?.role === "admin",
    },
  }
)

export const config = { matcher: ["/admin"] }
```

I created an Auth0 account, created a user and assigned a role to the user, but this role doesn't show up in the user token.

I found the documentation for [authenticating a user and request standard claims with Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/apis/scopes/sample-use-cases-scopes-and-claims), is this where I need to look at?  When testing the code

```js
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {

  if (event.authorization) {
    // Set claims 
    api.idToken.setCustomClaim("userData", JSON.stringify(event.user));
  }
};
```

however, I don't see any roles showing up in `userData`, maybe because the test user isn't assigned to any role?

Also I found the documentation of [requesting user's roles](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/users/get-user-roles).  Would it make sense to put this request into the middleware, so that instead of `authorized: ({ token }) => token?.role === "admin"` I request the user's roles from the end point?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I got it:

First create a Login / Post Login action in Auth0:

```js
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
  if (event.authorization) {
    api.idToken.setCustomClaim("https://example.com/roles", event.authorization.roles);
  }
};
```

then configure your auth route

```js
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.AUTH0_ISSUER,
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.nickname,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
          roles: profile["https://example.com/roles"]
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
```

I don't know if this is best practice, and also I don't understand exactly the role of namespaces (it's explained [here](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/create-custom-claims)) but this code seems to work so far!